# SwipeRefreshView, CollapsingToolbar, and RecyclerView

Tags: android, toolbar, swiperefreshlayout, appbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]

The refresh indicator doesn't display on top. Instead, it displays on top of Recycler view. However, I need it to display on top like Gmail, Google Plus etc.

Heres the layout code and MainActivity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="252dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/random"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="152dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

int mutedColor = R.attr.colorPrimary;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Sudarshan Sunder");
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.header);
    bmp = CircularImageBitmap.getCroppedBitmap(bmp, 200);
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentView);
    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.bar);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    appBarLayout.removeOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: I think it's displaying correctly,the swipe refresh as seen from the xml is below the app bar layout which surround the toolbar and the image so technically you're telling android that it should be below the image which is exactly where it has placed it

Comment: Now that i have never tried out but you can always do a trial and error solution and see what works out best for you,if it does not am sure someone here will come up with a solution for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, that must show indicator at the bottom of ActionBar

```
int[] actionBarSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize };
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, actionBarSizeAttr);
int actionBarSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 100);
a.recycle();
swipeRef.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0, actionBarSize);
swipeRef.setProgressViewEndTarget(false, actionBarSize);
```

Comment: What is the variable "act"?

Comment: Try updated answer. I add this line: `swipeRef.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0, actionBarSize);`